# encrypt some texts in Grails Config and DataSource files

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I need a trusted plugin or a way to encrypt some texts in Grails **Config** file and the DB passwords in **DataSource** . as they are sensitive data , such as email username and password.
Is there a powerful and trustful way to do this

Answer (score 3):

Not through a plugin, but it's possible to hide these sensitive config settings away in external files and then set appropriate file permissions on the external files so that they are only accessible to certain users.

Within `Config.groovy`, there is a setting for external [configuration files](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#configExternalized):

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:${appName}/externalDb.properties",
    ...
]
```

Within `DataSource.groovy`, a typical arrangement may be:

```
dataSource {
    username = "yourUser"
    password = "yourPassword"
    ...
}
```

Within your `externalDb.properties` (which would protected by your filesystem), you would then have the username/password/email/etc. overwritten:

```
dataSource.username = "prodUser"
dataSource.password = "secret1!"
```

You can leave the `Config.groovy` settings in-place and they will only be overwritten if the external config file is found.  You could use this to your advantage by using the external files on prod and relying on the `Config.groovy` settings for your dev environments; you can also apply this logic to having different external config files per environment (we use JNDI at work but I think this built-in grails feature is even easier).

Comment: but still the sensitive data exposed even i put it in an external file , what i'm searching for is to keep the data in **config** or **dataSource** but it will not be human readable for example `db password= $10$yyJApVd5aC2LPGak03frCuyf6SK38TqL/n/iok4Z2FfeDsS.mEPEC`

Comment: It's not exposed if you have file permissions properly set.

Comment: so is there a way to do it as i mentioned in my last comment ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we had done it

we were defining the password in the Config.Groovy as follows

```
password = DESCodec.decode("String Returned by the output of encode")




class DESCodec {
    def static encode = { String target ->
        def cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)
        return cipher.doFinal(target.bytes).encodeBase64() as String
    }

    def static decode = { String target ->
        def cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(target.decodeBase64())) as String
    }

    private static getCipher(mode) {
        def keySpec = new DESKeySpec(getPassword())
        def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES")
        def keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES")
        cipher.init(mode, keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec))
        return cipher
    }

    private static getPassword() {
        "testsaltString".getBytes("UTF-8")
    }


    static void main(args) {

        println args
        if(args.length == 1) {
            println encode(args[0])
        } else {

             println decode(args[1])
        }
    }
}
```

> run from the command line
>
> groovy DESCodec.groovy 'password'
>
> to get the ciphertext for the a string, and use the cipher text in
>   the config files...

Comment: Considering that if a user had access to Config.groovy they either most likely have access to the source code or to the generated bytecode, what does this buy you? Sure, the password might be mildly obfuscated but ultimately the password is still out there.

Comment: Config.groovy will be compiled it won't be available as it is. Since the application is deployed as war file I don't think the source code will be available, unless the code is deployed along with the class file. Pointing it to a property file which has tight permission has its risks. Lets say the account gets hacked, what are the chances of somebody going to thru class files vs reading properties file.